# Where do I start developing applications for java compatible cell phones?

Tags: java, mobile

Every time I look for mobile phone development I see Android, WinMobile, iPhone, RIM, etc...

Are small phone applications dead? I remember having a small collection of games and apps that run on motorola, sony ericsson and any other java-compatible phone. My Question is:

How do I start developing those applications? Is there some kind of market for them? And, last but not least, Are these applications dead with the arrival of complex UIs and devices like iPad, iPhones, Android, etc...?

thanks and hope someone can throw some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought a cheap phone for my mom today that used Brew as its O/S.  Those small Java apps would be ideal for such a phone, and it was humbling realizing that still the majority of the world don't really use "smartphones". However, the problem is there's so many different phones, different brands, and no centralized market place, making such an attempt difficult at best.  If you want to program Java apps for mobile phones, Android still uses Java.

Comment: you've got a point on Android, and I've dug into it, still Im curious about the others. There are literally thousands of apps of that kind!!

Comment: well it's safe to say that Android is going to be around for a long time, both in mobile and tablet form.  No harm in learning it!

Answer (score 0):

David i think these simple application have market but not really comparable to new technology.And, In my views the first step must be J2me.